# function of char * return values

Tags: c

i have problem with function of char * return values

my function is

```
    char * GetUnreadMessageIndexes(char * input)
{
   char index [10];
    int i=0;
    while(*input != ':')
    {
        input++;
    }

    input++;

    while(*input != ',')
    {
        if(*input != ' ')
        {
        index[i]= *input;
        i++;
        }

        input++;

    }

    return index;
};
```

and my test code in the main is

```
char * b = "+CMGL:26867689, \"REC READ\",\"+81923733737\", \n test again ";

char * a = GetUnreadMessageIndexes(b);


while(a != ((int)a + (int) strlen(a)))
{
    printf("%c",*a);
    a++;
}
```

this function suppose to parse the string of numbers after +CMGL: and before ,
i get the first number only "2" and the other values are unexpected values and not correct

Comment: Depending on the compiler, this scenario usually gives warnings/errors. If it didn't then you should enable the warning as this will catch errors that can be hard to debug.

Comment: Check the last edit on my answer about printing the resulting array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `index` is a local variable to the function `GetUnreadMessageIndexes` and once the execution of it ends, `index` is no more exisits. Use a pointer and allocate memory for 10 `char` using `malloc`.

Replace:

```
char index[0];
```

with:

```
char *index = malloc(10);
```

Also you need to null terminate the array otherwise `strlen` will not work properly with it:

```
while(*input != ',')
{
    if(*input != ' ')
    {
    index[i]= *input;
    i++;
    }

    input++;
}
index[i] = '\0';
```

Since now the array is null terminated instead of using the `while` loop to print the resulted array just use:

```
printf("%s", a);
```

And now your code is working as expected: [Live Demo](https://eval.in/93631)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing back a pointer to a variable ("index") that exists on the stack.  Once you leave the function the stack is going to unwind and your pointer is going point to something that has been overwritten by whatever new data is place on the stack.

Comment: what is the alternative choice without using global variables??

Comment: malloc the memory for index either before or within the call and remember to free it when done.  It might make sense to pass it in as a variable to the func.  Really depends on what you are ultimately doing with it.

Answer (score 1):

`index` is local to the function (as it is part of the stack) which may or may not be cleared as soon as the function exits. The target mem pointed to does not necessarily have to have the original values anymore and could/is/will be used elsewhere.

Comment: "... which _may_ be cleared ..." It also may not. This is UB as defined by the standard.